# Cant play byte array video on apple devices

Tags: asp.net-core, streaming

I am trying to play a video file which gets sent as a byte array to the client. 
It works on android and PC but not on apple devices.

I already tried adding the content range header(not quite sure if this is right), but this didn't do the trick either.

uploading/saving file

```
    var file = await RegisterFileAsync(formFile, uploaderId, categories, packages);
        try
        {          
            var filePath = FileStorePath + file.Id;

            if (formFile.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }

            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException($"File not found ({filePath}) trying to register a file in the database.");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            await UnregisterFileAsync(file.Id);
        }

        return file;
```

Looks like this:
[image]

Backend, sending file to the client:

```
    [HttpHead("[controller]/[action]/{id}")]
    [HttpGet("[controller]/[action]/{id}"), HttpGet("[controller]/{id}", Order = 1)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        var file = await fileService.GetFileById(id.Value, loadContent: true);

        if (file.ContentType.Equals("video/mp4"))
        {
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Range", "bytes 0-" + (file.Size - 1) + "/" + file.Size);
        }

        return File(file.Content, file.ContentType);
    }
```

Response Headers

[image]

HTML video player

[image]

Comment: There's not enough here to give you an answer. FWIW, MP4 is the container. What matters most for platform-specific issues is the codec. What codec is the video encoded with?

Comment: how can i get that information?

Comment: File properties maybe? Where did you get the video from?